# Convert seconds into minutes and seconds with Google calculator

Tags: google-calculator

How can I convert seconds into minutes and seconds using Google Calculator?

"237 seconds in minutes" gives me 3.95 minutes, but I want 3 minutes 57 seconds, and typing in "237 seconds in minutes and seconds" doesn't give me anything in Google Calculator.

Comment: I don't think you can unfortunately. The "unit converter" literally converts from one unit to the other (eg. "seconds" to "minutes" as in your example).  Whilst you can do base conversion eg. `237 in base 16`, it doesn't handle base 60. Reference: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3284611?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use Bing, you can get it by adding `in minutes and seconds` to the end of the value.

[image: Example of seconds to minutes and seconds]

It even [preserves fractional seconds](http://www.bing.com/search?q=10000.5+seconds+in+minutes+and+seconds).

(I'm as surprised as anyone that Bing can do something Google doesn't.)

Answer (score 2):

Not ideal, but you can easily do it in two steps.

1. "237 seconds in minutes" → 3.95
2. ".95 minutes in seconds" →  57

Truncate the first and you have *3 minutes* and from the second *57 seconds*.